# CoreData detecting deleted entity after save

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data

if i delete an cd entity and than save the mod

```
[self.moc deleteObject:(NSManagedObject *)someCDEntity];

[self saveMoc];
```

the pointers to this cd entity will become faults

by trying accessing the fault or ask for isDeleted, i get a

```
'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for
```

the problem is, as soon as i save the mod, the isDeleted doesn't work any more

**so how can i detect if an entity is removed? because just asking for isFault, doesn't indicate that it was deleted... and i cannot use isDeleted**

Comment: What for do you need to know, if some particular object is deleted after MOC saving?

Comment: yup, exactly thats what i want to know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found help in this OSX oriented thread

[How can I tell whether an `NSManagedObject` has been deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340445/how-can-i-tell-whether-an-nsmanagedobject-has-been-deleted/7896369#7896369)

```
- (BOOL) entityWasDeleted:(SomeEntity *)someEntity {

    return ((someEntity == nil) || ([self.moc existingObjectWithID:someEntity.objectID error:NULL] == nil));
}
```

**Beware : don't use the code bellow, as it might not always work**

```
if (managedObject.managedObjectContext == nil) {
    // Assume that the managed object has been deleted = might not always work
}
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the beware, as I was just about to implement it that way. It makes sense that the first snippet is more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I use the prepareForDeletion method in NSManagedObject. It is called just before the deletion but while the object is still valid ( and not faulted ). Works like a charm!

Comment: yes, but i want to test after moc save