# Core Data: executeFetchRequest:error: returns objects with no managedObjectContext

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am running into an issue where `NSManagedObjectContext`'s `executeFetchRequest:error:` is returning an array of `NSManagedObjects` that haven't been inserted in the context.

My method:

```
- (NSArray *)deleteAllObjectsWithEntityName:(NSString *)entityName {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    fetchRequest.entity = entityDesc;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *managedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    // [[self.managedObjectContext registeredObjects] count] : 0
    // [[self.managedObjectContext insertedObjects] count] : 0
    //
    // managedObjects.count : 1
    // error : nil
    //
    // managedObjects[0] : <Foo: 0xe98c1d0>
    // managedObjects[0].isDeleted : NO
    // managedObjects[0].isFault : NO
    // managedObjects[0].isInserted : NO
    // managedObjects[0].managedObjectContext : nil
    //
    // [NSThread isMainThread] : YES
    //
    // self.managedObjectContext : <NSManagedObjectContext: 0xe97d840>
    //

    for (NSManagedObject *anObject in managedObjects) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
    }

    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];

    // error : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 \
    // "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134030.)" UserInfo=0x8b6d260 \
    // {NSAffectedObjectsErrorKey=(
    //     "<Foo: 0x10464910> (entity: Foo; id: 0x10464950 <x-coredata:///Job/tE5188F9B-9DC4-4EA2-8636-7790587E114F242> ; data: {...})"
    // ), \
    // NSUnderlyingException=Cannot update object that was never inserted.},
}
```

I've verified that `self.managedObjectContext` is always created on the main thread.

According to [NSManagedObjectContext Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html), the object is automatically registered with the fetching managedObjectContext, so I find it suspicious that `registeredObjects` returns an empty set.

I'm stumped, so am hoping someone out there can spot something wrong with my code, or knows about some gotcha that I've missed.

Comment: What do you mean by haven't been inserted in the context?

Comment: I mean that the objects all have a nil managedObjectContext.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help, but I'd try calling `processPendingChanges` on the managed object context after inserting the object in question and before running the code above. Maybe just make it the first line in the method above.

Comment: Gave it a shot but no change. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a symptom of updating the managed object after it has been deleted and its context has been saved.

I was keeping a reference to the Foo instance in a view controller. I deleted all Foo objects from the managed object context, then updated the Foo instance, then tried to delete all Foo objects again.

This question helped me track down the cause: [How can I tell whether an `NSManagedObject` has been deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340445/how-can-i-tell-whether-an-nsmanagedobject-has-been-deleted).