# Can I safely wrap 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault' errors in a @try catch block

Tags: ios, core-data

I understand why this error happens: when you try to access a CoreData object that was deleted in a managed object context on another thread, and is hence set to a 'fault' object, and any retained references will therefore no longer point to a valid CoreData object.

I am using a NSFetchedResultsController.

I have confirmed that all the code is implemented correctly. I have 2 managed object contexts, one intended for a BG thread and one for the main thread.

I have confirmed that the main thread is subscribed for notifications under NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification.

I have confirmed that when this notification fires, I perform a mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification: on the main thread managed object context.

I am NOT retaining these objects anywhere, but I am setting the batch size for the NSFetchRequest (Is this potentially the issue?)

YET, I still occasionally get the 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault' error.

In my particular application, this usually happens during a sort of "data-bind" process so I could safely just discard fault objects and move on. I would like to do this by wrapping the inside of the loop that data-binds in a @try-catch block and just skip rows that I get the CoreData error for.

Can I safely do this with CoreData? Or do I need to completely dump the managed object context after I encounter a fault.

I did check this question about [how to check if a CoreData object is a fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340445/how-can-i-tell-whether-an-nsmanagedobject-has-been-deleted/7896369#7896369), which might be something I implement if I can't safely assume that my @try-catch block won't cause other issues.

Comment: I wrapped it in a try catch block and it seems to have reduced the number of crashes, but I am unsure if there are any long term effects from this.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of using try-catch we can use "existingOjectWithId" and check for nil on returned object.

```
- (NSManagedObject*)existingObjectWithID:(NSManagedObjectID*)objectID error:(NSError**)error
```

The above returns the object for the specified ID if it is already registered in the context, or faults the object into the context. ***If the object cannot be fetched, or does not exist, or cannot be faulted, it returns nil***. Unlike -objectWithID: it never returns a fault.

Comment: This is a good approach, but the question is about if it's specifically possible to use try and catch. I will give you a +1 though :)